# Decode php file

Tags: php, decode

my php file is encoded.
What method was used?
please help me to decode this file.
my code :

```
<?php
eval(pack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

?>
```

and :

```
<?php

eval(pack('H*','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'));
$pars_pwfi = '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';    
?>
```

thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hex to ASCII:

```
eval(base64_decode('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'));
```

Base64 decode:

```
function wp_expired_the_theme_message() { if (empty($_REQUEST["theme_expired"])) { $theme_expired_false = get_bloginfo("url") . "/index.php?theme_expired=true"; echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=$theme_expired_false\">"; exit(); } else { echo ("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /><div style=\"padding:20px; margin: 20px; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; background: #fff; color: #c00;\"><p> برای دریافت لایسنس آدرس سایت خود را ارسال کنید  </p>ParsWP.ir<p></p></div>"); } }
```

Comment: What sites or application have you used?

Answer (score 0):

Pack is used for binary data. 
I don't know what this is. Looks more hexedecimal to me.